# Having Trouble Downloading Hyperledger fabric docker images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, docker-image, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Background: I just downloaded docker, docker-compose, node.js,npm, and the hyperledger samples from the offical documentation. However, when I downloaded the hyperledger sample networks,everything seemed to be going fine until the script tried pulling the Hyperledger fabric docker images. This is the error message:

```
===> Pulling fabric Images

====> hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.1.0

Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var
/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/images
/create?fromImage=hyperledger%2Ffabric-peer&tag=2.1.0: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: 
connect: permission denied
```

NOTE: I am using ubuntu 18.04.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing: either the Docker service is not running, or your user does not have permission to access the Docker service (more likely).

Running your command as `sudo` is one way to fix it. Or have a look at this question: [How can I use docker without sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/q/477551/117753) (but be careful about the security trade-offs!)

Answer (score 0):

add sudo to the  command while you are pulling your docker images using curl.

sudo curl -sSL fabric-binaries-link | bash -s

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution would be to change the permission of docker.sock file

Go the terminal and type the following and press enter.

```
sudo chmod 775 //var/run/docker.sock
```

However,  it is not advised to use the root user for installing software for fabric. Instead, you can do the following:

1. Create a new user

   ```
   sudo adduser bibek
   ```
2. Add our user to the sudo group.

   ```
   sudo usermod -aG sudo bibek
   ```
3. Switch to new user

   ```
   su - bibek
   ```
4. Then you can install all docker and docker-compose

   ```
   sudo apt-get install docker.io docker-compose
   ```
5. Start and enable docker

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER 
   sudo systemctl start docker 
   sudo systemctl enable docker
   ```
6. You can check if the installation worked by running:

   ```
   docker run hello-world
   ```

Cheers!